# Help finding a transversal to equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to show that a relation is an equivalence relation and find a transversal. The relation is defined as $\sim$ on $ℕ$ given by $a \sim b \iff$ there are $n,m
 \in ℕ$ with $a|b^n$ and $b|a^m$.

I have shown that it's an equivalence relation, and now need to find a transversal. I think I'm supposed to use prime factorization, but am not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that

$$a\sim b\iff\exists m,n\in \Bbb N,\; a|b^m, b|a^n$$
and

$$b\sim c\iff \exists p,q\in\Bbb N,\; b|c^p, c|b^q\implies b^m|c^{pm}$$
and
$$ b|a^n\implies b^q|a^{nq}$$
hence we see that
$$a|c^{pm}, c|a^{nq}\iff a\sim c$$

Comment: That's transitivity